# How to read line word by word in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to read N lines like:

```
"word1" "word2"
"word1" "word2"
      .
      .
      .
"word1" "word2"
```

And then read one big line T, where |T| <= 11000000, I mean it may consists out of about 11*10^6 letters.
My task is to replace all words1 in T by words2.
But the problem is that I have only 10Mb of memory and I think one of the solutions may consists of reading a line T word by word and printing, I mean using O(1) memory.
But I have no glue how to make it on python.
Thanks in advance)

Comment: Do you know `N` in advance, so you can switch from reading entire lines at once to simply reading fixed size chunks of the big line?

Answer (score -1):

## I am not sure about the memory issue but I hope this will help

### Replacing words

If you know which words you want to replace you can do this:

```py
newT = T.replace("word1","word2")
```

### Dividing sentence in to words

source of code example: https://www.guru99.com/tokenize-words-sentences-nltk.html

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
text = "God is Great! I won a lottery."
print(word_tokenize(text))

Output: ['God', 'is', 'Great', '!', 'I', 'won', 'a', 'lottery', '.']
```

Comment: Yeah, I know all this. But it doesn't work(